# how to fix java array skip first user input at first inside a for loop

Tags: java

I want to fill a multidimensional array using user input inside a loop but it skips the first input and proceeds to the next. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("number of batches: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("number of students: ");
    int b = input.nextInt();
    String[][] list = new String[a][b];
    String name;
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            System.out.print("enter a student: ");
            list[j][i] = input.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
}
```

here is the result:

```
number of batches: 2

number of students: 3

enter a student: enter a student:
```

//the first input was skipped

Comment: how to solve this sir?

Comment: Click the link in [the comment pasted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604104/how-to-fix-java-array-skip-first-user-input-at-first-inside-a-for-loop#comment96003812_54604104)